# when adding a new inline to my formset, my datepickers stop working

Tags: jquery, django, datepicker, inline-formset

Bit of a strange one today.

I've a very basic project. A form and added to that I have an inline form. It's books to authors.

When the form loads(/authors/create/) I have a author name and underneath I have a form where I can add books to that author.

To be able to have dynamic inlines(able to add or remove on the form) I'm using http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/.

My problem now is that when I add a new inline, all my datepickers(for the date published fields) for the inline form stops working.

[I have attached my sample project showing exactly what is wrong. You can download and run it here.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8390390/books_authors_inlines.zip)

**Why and how can I fix this?**

Comment: Sorry, not going to download your zip. But when you say datepickers stop working, do you mean existing ones, or the new ones that have just been added?

Comment: the date fields that render on load seem to be fine. then when i add a new row all the date pickers in the inline formset go out the window, even the ones that initially worked. but datepickers that are associated to different forms or formsets continue working. just the datepickers that are part of that inline formset break.

Comment: To be honest it seems to work very well using Django 1.3 and Safari  5.1 (7534.48.3).

Comment: I keep getting: `No module named books_authors_inlines.urls`, have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sure there is cleaner and more clever way to do it. But working proof of concept:

```
function renewDatePickers() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
}

$(renewDatePickers);

$(function() {
    $('.form-row.inline.{{ book_form.prefix }}').formset({
        prefix: '{{ book_form.prefix }}',
        added: renewDatePickers // Event -- read inline docs
    });
})
```

And take Your JS code from `base.html` to `author_form.html`

Comment: thank you. reinitialising the datepickers on each add of an inline is very smart. i also did it on the remove event and now it works great.